# interactive input error instead of creating the object

Tags: python

On my learning phase of python (2.7). I am following a "how to" book, and this is the first thing that has not worked. The topic is interactive inputs.

They give the code, which I think I typed in correctly:

```
name=input('Enter your name  ')
```

I then execute the line and it gives me the prompt I would expect:

```
Enter your name
```

Next to the prompt, I type in my name and press enter. But instead of it creating an object I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Myles' is not defined
```

I have done this both in IDLE and my IDE (Spyder) and get the same error. So what dumb thing am I doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use:

```
name = input(...)
```

Use:

```
name = raw_input(...)
```

Comment: I guess his tutorial may be for Python 3, where the raw_input() function has been renamed input()

Comment: That worked! 1) what is the difference (curious) 2) my book does several of these =input(..) examples, curious why they do that (if it does not work correctly).

Comment: @meepmeep- I'll check on the version of the book. But that would explain everything. Oddly enough, everyone tells me to work in 2.7 and not touch 3.X. Thanks

Comment: Is almost the same, try googling "Python 3.x vs Python 2.7"

Comment: @mylesg The very betst way to thank someone on thi site is to accept his answer by clicking on the check mark.